# Grant S3 access to EC2 instance (simplest case)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I tried with simplest case following [AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-access-s3-bucket/). I created role, assigned to instance and rebooted instance. To test access interactively, I logon to Windows instance and run `aws s3api list-objects --bucket testbucket`. I get error `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied`.
Next test was to create .aws/credentials file and add profile to assume role. I modified role (assigned to instance) and added permission to assume role by any user in account. When I run same command `aws s3api list-objects --bucket testbucket --profile assume_role`, objects in bucket are listed.
Here is my test role Trust Relationship

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "ec2.amazonaws.com",
                    "ssm.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "UserCanAssumeRole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "111111111111"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Role has only one permission "AmazonS3FullAccess".
When I switch role in AWS console, I can see content of S3 bucket (and no other action is allowed in AWS console).
My assumption is that EC2 instance does not assume role.
How to pinpoint where is the problem?

Comment: From your description, you have done everything correctly. You could try running `aws sts get-caller-identity` to confirm what credentials AWS thinks you are using (but you would also need to grant STS permissions to the IAM Role).

Comment: Thanks for tip. I solwed problem. Since proxy was called, none of AWS command would succeed since no access token.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with Windows proxy.
I checked proxy environment variables. None was set. When I checked Control Panel->Internet options I saw that Proxy text box shows value of proxy, but checkbox "Use proxy" was not checked. Next to it was text "Some of your settings are managed by organization." Skip proxy was having 169.254.169.254 listed.
I run command in debug mode and saw that CLI connects to proxy. Which cannot access 169.254.169.254 and no credentials are set. When I explicitly set environment variable `set NO_PROXY=169.254.169.254` everything started to work.
Why AWS CLI uses proxy from Windows system I do not understand. Worst of all, it uses proxy but does not check bypass proxy.  Lesson learned. **Run command in debug mode and verify output.**